# How to use Selection.Paragraphs.Count in Word to repeat a process X number of times

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010

I select X number of paragraphs in Word and want to activate a macro that performs the same action on each paragraph.  The action is adding a style separator before the first period in each paragraph and then applying 2 styles, 1 before the period and one after.

I know how to write this code. However, I've spent hours trying various chunks of code to repeat this process on each of the selected paragraphs, with no luck.

I think the Selection.Paragraphs.Count may help me, in that it gives me the number of paragraphs selected, but I don't know how to incorporate it in my VBA to repeat my process X number of times, X being the number of paragraphs selected.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. **We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems**. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `for each p in selection.paragraphs` or `for i=1 to selection.paragraphs.count ... selection.paragraphs(i) ...` could help